# Process multiple inputs to a Kettle step

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am trying to create a step where I have two inputs. Both of them should be in the same format. I need to process using these two input streams and output one stream.

Below is the code I have so far in processRow():

```
List<StreamInterface> infoStreams = meta.getStepIOMeta().getInfoStreams();

data.oneRowSet = findInputRowSet(infoStreams.get(0).getStepname());
data.twoRowSet = findInputRowSet(infoStreams.get(1).getStepname());
```

if its the first row and the following for all rows:

```
data.one = getRowFrom(data.oneRowSet);
data.two = getRowFrom(data.twoRowSet);

if (data.one == null && data.two == null) {
      setOutputDone();
      return false;
}
```

However on the line `data.oneRowSet = findInputRowSet(infoStreams.get(0).getStepname());`, I get the following error: `The source step to read from [null] couldn't be found`.

Your inputs on this would be really helpful. Thanks.

EDIT: I have added an example transformation and the source code of my step here: https://github.com/adeydas/KettleMultipleStreams/tree/develop

Comment: Do you have an example transformation for which this doesn't work? Which steps are wired into your step, and what are the steps' names? Do they show up as Info steps in Spoon (i.e. a question mark on the hop arrow)?

Comment: I have two CSV input steps wired into my step. They do not show up as info steps. The step they converge into is what I am trying to create. The example transformation is here: https://github.com/adeydas/KettleMultipleStreams/blob/develop/multiple_test.ktr and the source code is at https://github.com/adeydas/KettleMultipleStreams/tree/develop/src/main/java/ws/abhis/kettle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution. I wrote a small "how-to" on it here: http://abhis.ws/display/KKB/Kettle+transformation+step+with+multiple+input+streams and the code is on GitHub: https://github.com/adeydas/KettleMultipleStreams.